# how i can scroll in ptpython 'help' window

Tags: python, ptpython, python-prompt-toolkit

is there any way how I can scroll inside 'help' window in ptpython repl? When I type the name of a function a help opens at the bottom, but I don't know how i can scroll it up/down (or search inside it). Is this possible? I know about the `repl.enable_mouse_support = Tru`e in which case i can scroll it via mouse. But this has also effect on copy/paste functionality and other behaviour related to mouse. I would like to just focus on the 'main' window and 'help' window and have the ability to scroll in it via keyboard.
[image]

Comment: I've tried all of the "standard" hotkeys for this action and nothing has worked, so it may not be (currently) possible.